# Passing form data as well as list value into HTML Page using flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to pass both form data as well as list value in flask. But the form data does not come in the output. I am new to python. Sorry if my question sounds too stupid!
 Here is the flask code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('a.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_form_post():
result = request.form['username']
list1=['Who is the president of India?','Who is the captain of Team 
        India?','In which year was Mahatma Gandhi born?'];
return render_template('welcome.html', result=result, lis=list1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to the quiz {{result.username}}
{{lis[0]}} 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the form page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/">
Welcome to the quiz. Please Enter your name to proceed!
Name: <input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" name="submitdata">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the output as:
Welcome to the quiz Who is the president of India?
Why does the name entered does not come in output? However, if I just change this line code

```
return render_template('welcome.html', result=result)
```

I get the output as Welcome to the quiz xyz.
So why can't I pass multiple variables in render_template()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have this:

```
@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('a.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_form_post():
```

You have defined two routes with the same identifier `'/'`. The latter one will be used and the first one will be completely ignored.

When the code is executed first time (as a GET) there is no form to provide a `username` string so it is not rendered, which explains your output, "Welcome to the quiz Who is the president of India?"